# Communicating between an activity and a fragment

Tags: android

I'm coding Story app, and i want user can change size, font of content. The change of the value is done in activity and send to fragment throught interface. But I have a problem with interface (NullPointer), `onSettingChangedListener` is not null when I call `setOnSettingChangedListener` but when I check in `setSize()` then is **null**. Please tell me why?

Here is code

**ChapterActivity.class**

```
public class ChapterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private OnSettingChangedListener onSettingChangedListener;

    private static ChapterActivity mInstances;

    public static ChapterActivity getInstance() {
        if (mInstances == null)
            mInstances = new ChapterActivity();
        return mInstances;
    }

    private void setSize(int mode) {
        text_size = mode;
        SharedManager.putInt(mContext, PREF_TEXT_SIZE, text_size);
        if (onSettingChangedListener != null)
            onSettingChangedListener.onTextSizeChanged(mode);
        Log.d(TAG, "setSize: " + (onSettingChangedListener == null ? " Null" : " not null"));
    }

    public interface OnSettingChangedListener {
        public void onTextSizeChanged(int mode);

        public void onTextFontChanged(String fontName);
    }

    public void setOnSettingChangedListener(OnSettingChangedListener onSettingChangedListener) {
        this.onSettingChangedListener = onSettingChangedListener;
        Log.d(TAG, "setOnSetting: " + (onSettingChangedListener == null ? " Null" : "Not null"));
    }
}
```

**ChapterFragment**

```
public class ChapterFragment extends Fragment 
    implements ChapterActivity.OnSettingChangedListener {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_chapter, container, false);
        mContext = getActivity();

        txtContent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);
        txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        // Add Listener
        ChapterActivity.getInstance().setOnSettingChangedListener(this);

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTextSizeChanged(int mode) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(mode));
        if (mode == ChapterActivity.TEXT_SIZE.SMALL.id) {
            setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Small);
        } else if (mode == ChapterActivity.TEXT_SIZE.MEDIUM.id) {
            setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Medium);
        } else {
            setTextAppearance(android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Large);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextFontChanged(String fontName) {
        Log.d(TAG, fontName);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

`setOnSetting: not null
setSize: null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not treat your activities as a Singleton. Having the `getInstance()` method does not work as the Android Framework handles creating activities for you and the one you create yourself will not be used the way you think it is.

You need to get the activity your `ChapterFragment` is currently attached to and set the callback on that.

Change: `ChapterActivity.getInstance().setOnSettingChangedListener(this);`
To: `((ChapterActivity) getActivity()).setOnSettingChangedListener(this)`

Or remove that line and add the below method to `ChapterFragment`.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    ((ChapterActivity) activity).setOnSettingChangedListener(this);
}
```

If you are using the support library for fragments or are targeting API 23+ the new `onAttach` method takes a context as a parameter instead:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    ((ChapterActivity) context).setOnSettingChangedListener(this);
}
```